# Will the Git repository increase in size when creating local branches?

Tags: git

I have just cloned a repo that is 600 MB with 7 remote branches.

Will the size increase of the repo when I start creating local branches - e.g new stuff getting pulled down from remote(I expect NOT since you get everything locally when you clone) server or de-compressed on the fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creating a local branch is not pulling in remote commits!

However, I assume you're asking

> I have a clone of a ~600MB remote with 7 branches. If I locally `git checkout` one of these branches, will the storage size increase?

The answer is: yes. It might. Basically, a commit is a snapshot of current file state of all files modified since the previous commit. So checking out a branch means that you might get working copies of files that weren't there before. Also, git *can* use compressed object storage.